# Having trouble comparing integers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with a function which compares integers.

I assigned the input and used the parseInt method, but the method did not work as I expected. I have looked at different solutions, but had no luck.

This is the part of the code which I'm having trouble with:

```
            <form>
                <label>QUESTION 4 <br /></label>
                <label for="q4">How long is the Pieterad, the most famous walking trail in Ashington?(In Kilometers)</label>
                <input type="text" id="q4" placeholder="Enter your answer here." />
                <button onclick="q4function()" type="button">Submit</button>
                <p id="q4Answer"></p>
            </form>

        function q4Funtion() {
            var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("q4").value, 10);

            if (a == 498)
                document.getElementById("q4Answer").innerHTML = "Great Success!";
            else if (a != 498)
                document.getElementById("q4Answer").innerHTML = "The answer was 498.";    
        }
```

I am getting no result from this function at all. I am not sure what have done wrong.

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work"? What happens, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Check your browser console. The chances are your form is being submitted so maybe add `event.preventDefault();` into your function

Comment: How did you separately test that this was the only function without a result? and when you mean without a result, you mean it gives a response of 'null' or does it return empty?

Comment: if is is one thing why check in the else branch again as to what you are expecting? if won't be 498 if you got there already :)

Comment: I think you just have a typo - your function name is `q4Funtion` but you are calling `q4function `

Comment: I'm ashamed. @brbcoding you were correct, I had multiple spelling errors. Thank you.

Comment: This is a typo question and [should be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you spell "Function" correctly :) Also look into event handlers rather than the onclick method.

```
function q4Function() {
            var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("q4").value, 10);

            if (a == 498)
                document.getElementById("q4Answer").innerHTML = "Great Success!";
            else if (a != 498)
                document.getElementById("q4Answer").innerHTML = "The answer was 498.";    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is likely being submitted meaning your JavaScript code isn't running. Adding this prevents it:

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", e => e.preventDefault());
```

Also make sure you're spelling `function` correctly:

```
function q4Function() {...}
```